# How do I compile guppy for Windows 64 bit Python 2.7?

Tags: python, memory-management, python-2.7

I'm trying to use guppy to do some memory analysis for my Python program. I am using Windows 7 with Python 2.7 64-bit. I have checked out the latest version of guppy from the trunk:

`svn co https://guppy-pe.svn.sourceforge.net/svnroot/guppy-pe/trunk/guppy guppy`

When I do `python setup.py build` I get a bunch of errors. Has anyone compiled guppy for Windows 7 Python 2.7 64-bit? If so, how? If this isn't possible, what other Python memory analyzers would I be able to use? Thanks.

Comment: Please include the errors (you can edit your question)...

Comment: a couple of days ago I met the same problem trying to compile guppy with mingw32. As result, I found a comment on guppy sourceforge page saying that "the version can not be built by mingw32 on windows" and a link to a ready binary which happens to work for me.

Comment: @hallik, I can not find the comment anymore, but managed to find the link: http://www.sistemasagiles.com.ar/soft/guppy-0.1.10.win32-py2.7.exe

Comment: Hi, anyone found a binary for python 2.6 windows x64? Cannot find one for my development machine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use the VS X64 command prompt. I started "VS2013 x64 Cross Tools Command Prompt" (with 2013 Express for Desktop installed) and executed the build command, which completed without any errors.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! This project is long gone for me as I don't even work at the place where I was working on this. I think I ended up using some other memory analysis app.